# Android Manifest, Menu doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

So, in my application I have a start screen image + sound that stays up 2 seconds and then it enters in menu. The menu items looks like this:

```
<activity
     android:name=".helloWorld"
     android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ro.dixy.Boston_Tutorial_App.HELLOWORLD"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In my Menu.java file I have these code lines:

```
protected void onListItem(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{

    super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);
    String test = classes[position];
    try
    {
        //Selectare meniu in functie de nume(pozitie)
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("ro.dixy.Boston_Tutorial_App." + test);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The thing is that when I click a menu from "classes" it doesn't do anything.

I am new in Android and I am trying to learn it from Boston Tutorials.

Tell me if you need anything else. Thank you.

LE:

Menu.java

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity
{
//Nume Meniuri
String classes[] = {"helloWorld","TextPlay","example2","example3","example4","example5"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //ListAdapter pentru ListActivity
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

protected void onListItem(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String test = classes[position];
    try
    {
        //Selectare meniu in functie de nume(pozitie)
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("ro.dixy.Boston_Tutorial_App." + test);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you defining the menu event listener?

Comment: I'll edit my Question. Done. :D

Comment: It looks as if you expect to start other activities by clicking on their names in the ListView.  Does your manifest include those other activities ("TextPlay","example2","example3","example4", etc...)?

Comment: I don't care about other activites. I have 2 activities in android manifest that should work, helloWorld and TextPlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error. Here is the good code:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{ 
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with `startActivity` method. This method should have an `intent` and this intent should have the application `Context` and the `java` class in its constructor. As following

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

Make sure that you are passing the correct `context` and the correct `class` path

Comment: That was my first thought but I tried in many different ways and I doesn't work :(.

Comment: Are you trying to perform this code in Activity or fragment

Comment: Ok, pass its `context` instead of the context value

Comment: Well, "Menu.this" is the context. I mean that's what i know.

Comment: Post your Menu.java class in your question and tell me

Comment: You can look over it :D.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a list adapter, but where is the event listener?  I don't see one.

Example:

```
imgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);

    // set up listeners         
    imgLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        // put your code here

        });
```

Comment: I understood from the tutorial that I don't need an onClickListener anymore. And the strange part is that with my code, in the tutorial works(is video).

Comment: @user3175636  If I watched the same tutorial you did, then you need to add the override method `onListItemClicked`.  Either way, if you want your event to fire when tapped, there has to be a listener to handle it.

Comment: I get an error ("method does not override from its superclass") if I put @Override. My head hurts right now and I'm tired :)). I'll get back to the code tomorrow.

Comment: @user3175636  It sounds like you are not extending `ListActivity` and are using `Activity` instead.

Comment: I put the whole Menu.java class in my question so, as you can see, I'm using ListActivity.